# Commands to learn about an unfamiliar system

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, root

You log in to an unfamiliar UNIX or Linux system (as root). Which commands do you run to orient yourself and figure out what kind of system you are on? How do you figure out what type of hardware is in use, which type of operating system is running and what the current situation is when it comes to permissions and security?

What is the first and second command you type?

Comment: I would use `uname -a` then `apropos whatever `is your friend.

Comment: `nmap -A -T4 localhost` could also give you some useful info

Comment: @seumasmac netstat would be better and more efficient than nmapping the local machine.

Comment: @AndréBorie nmap and netstat produce quite different results. Therefore it doesn't make much sense to compare them with respect to efficiency (whatever kind of).

Comment: @AndréBorie I'd originally planned on putting a :) on the end of that. I'd been checking security on one of my own machines, and while holding my `nmap` hammer `localhost` suddenly looked like a nail.  But then I realised it actually does give some interesting information, so I left it as a semi-serious suggestion.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

a dual-use question! Either a Software Archaeologist or an Evil Hacker could use the answers to this question! Now, which am I?

I always used to use `ps -ef` versus `ps -augxww` to find out what I was on. Linux and System V boxes tended to like "-ef" and error on "-augxww", vice versa for BSD and old SunOS machines. The output of `ps` can let you know a lot as well.

If you can log in as root, and it's a Linux machine, you should do `lsusb` and `lspci` - that will get you 80% of the way towards knowing what the hardware situation is. `dmesg | more` can help you understand any current problems on just about anything.

It's beginning to be phased out, but doing `ifconfig -a` can usually tell you a lot about the network interfaces, and the networking. Running `mii-tool` and/or `ethtool` on the interfaces you see in `ifconfig` output that look like cabled ethernet can give you some info too.

Runnin `ip route` or `netstat -r` can be informative about Internet Protocol routing, and maybe something about in-use network interfaces.

A `mount` invocation can tell you about the disk(s) and how they're mounted.

Running `uptime`, and then `last | more` can tell you something about the current state of maintenance. Uptimes of 100+ days probably means "it's time to change the oil and fluids", metaphorically speaking. Running `who` is also

Looking at `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/etc/hosts` can tell you about the DNS setup of that machine. Maybe do `nslookup google.com` or `dig bing.com` to see if DNS is mostly functional.

It's always worth watching what errors ("command not found") and what variants of commands ("ps -ef" vs "ps augxww") work to determine what variant of Unix or Linux or BSD you just ended up on.

The presence or absence of a C compiler, and where it lives is important. Do `which cc` or better, `which -a cc` to find them.

Comment: I prefer `netstat -tulpanw` for more output but it is a matter of taste really.

Comment: There is also `lshw` under Linux.

Comment: `mount` is messy, `findmnt` is very clean instead.

Answer (score 10):

`cat /etc/*release*` is a nice command for getting an overview of which distro is running.

Answer (score 9):

http://bhami.com/rosetta.html might be handy to review, otherwise I usually poke around under `/etc` (accounts, init stuff, hints of OS flavor, etc) and `crontab -l` and look through the `ps` list for things to learn about.

Also "as root" is super scary, as I've had to fix systems where a Linux admin doing such an investigation set all the Solaris hostnames to `-f`.

Also `df` is a dangerous command, a great way to oh whoops hung on blocking I/O. So never run that until you've at least investigated the mounts, or know you can get another session open somehow.

Use very simple commands (`uname`, `cd /etc; ls`, `cat`, `$PAGER`) until you figure out what the host is, and if you're unfamiliar with it, check a rosetta or always read the man page before assuming some command or flag to a command does what it does on more popular systems.

Comment: Makes me wonder: is there a robust way of (temporarily) dropping into a lower-privileged environment? Or is this not feasible or somehow not a good idea?

Comment: @Oliphaunt: You could `su nobody`; I think that's pretty widely supported even on sudo systems where root's password is locked, provided you *start out* as root.

Comment: Why is `df` dangerous? Are there systems where it does something other than show filesystem usage?

Comment: @terdon kernel I/O blocking, e.g. on a hard NFS mount that's down; at best you can get a new session or terminal open somehow (time wasted during an outage), or at worst that was your only console onto that old Solaris system and uh yeah... maybe it will boot, maybe it won't, shame the mount information wasn't looked at first and that problematic NFS server line recognized...

Comment: If `df` hangs then you just CTRL-Z it and `kill -9` it. I've ran into that problem as well and that's always worked for me. Also, ideally your mounts shouldn't be hung. I also don't think many people think of programs hanging as "dangerous" which is why I think terdon was confused.

Comment: @Bratchley oh, never had a console connection you can't send control characters over? Um where was that zmodem manual, or oh geez how do we sent them through the buggy Java thing to that other buggy thing ah geez who has physical access?

Answer (score 4):

`dmidecode` and `lspci` will usually give you a good idea of what the hardware running on the system is. If this is a server usually running `netstat -tlpn` will give away the purpose of the server. `df -hP` is a good command for checking the current storage on the system. `lsb_release -a` should let you know what distro you're on:

```
[root@vle02 ~]# lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 (Santiago)
Release:        6.7
Codename:       Santiago
```

Running `last` should let you know who uses the system. Assuming you've accessed this server legitimately, often you can just ask one of the people who log into it for more information about it.

For vendor neutral security checks: Often times the firewall will have unique configuration data so running a `iptables -nvL` is useful. You should also check out your distro's pam configuration files to see if you're only using local users or if you're configured to use ldap/kerberos/winbind/sssd/whatever.

You could also inspect the configuration of the services that come up in your `netstat -tlpn`. For instance, if you see apache, you can look at `/etc/http/conf/httpd.conf` (on RHEL, `/etc/apache2` on Ubuntu) and try to see what websites are running. Alternatively you might do a `apachectl -S` to get a list of all the virtual hosts configured. It kind of fans out from there so all I can really do is offer apache as an example and just say to verify the daemon's configuration if it's something else.

On RHEL I would also check `rpm -qa --last | head` to see when the last time they did system updates. I would also check to see if SELinux is enabled via `getenforce`

Answer (score -2):

A few other ideas:

- Presence or absence of `/proc` filesystem may indicate if you're on
  [Mac](https://web.archive.org/web/20200103161748/http://osxbook.com/book/bonus/ancient/procfs/),
  [FreeBSD](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2098147), or
  Linux.
- Package management differs from Linux distro to distro. Debian-based ones have apt, such as Deepin, Ubuntu, Mint; Red Hat and Fedora had yum up to some point but now Fedora has [DNF](https://www.theregister.com/2015/05/31/fedora_22_review/); Arch uses pacman. So we could do something like this: `ls /usr/bin | grep 'apt\|yum\|pacman'`
- Presence of certain services on certain ports when viewing `netstat -tulpan`. The could be `sshd` , webserver, `ftp`;

Comment: Note that the presence of a given executable on the system doesn't really mean anything. Debian, for example, has a `yum` package. How would the presence of an ssh server indicate the system? AFAIK you can find `sshd` on pretty much anything.

Comment: @terdon True.  I'm just approaching this from the point of view of a new sysadmin where you get told "We have some Linux box overthere, go do something about it".  At that point you may be asking , well: Does it have remote access ? Is that remote access hardened ? Does it has package management I am familiar with or do I have to learn new package manager ? The goal isn't necessarily determining *what* OS you get, Bruce Ediger already covered that, but I'm focusing more on *investigating* the system itself